# Powershell need need assistance select-string command

Tags: powershell

I am new with powershell and I need some help with command.

Here is my data:
I am execute "db2 get dbm cfg" command I am getting below output:

Diagnostic data directory path (DIAGPATH) = c:\users\db2admin\

What I am want to return the value after the = sign, the output should look like this
c:\users\db2admin\

Here is the command I running to get the data, but I can’t figure out how to get c:\users\db2admin\

```
db2 get dbm cfg | select-string -Pattern DIAGPATH|? {-not($_ -match “ALT_DIAGPATH”)}
```

If ther an option to add to above command to print last value after = sign?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that's the only line you get from that command, a simple split should do it:

```
((db2 get dbm cfg) -split ' = ')[1]
```

Comment: Thank you very much this is what I was looking work.

Answer (score 0):

split on `=` and select the second result (Since the first result will be everything before the `=`) like this:

```
((db2 get dbm cfg | select-string -Pattern DIAGPATH|? {-not($_ -match “ALT_DIAGPATH”)}) -split "= ")[1]
```